# How to get value of input from specific <tr> tag and sum all the values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some fields coming from ajax request. Now I want to sum up all fields But doesn't work. Please help me to solve this small issue. Below is my code.

```
  $('.tree-id').click(function(e) {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $('#createtreeModal form #tree_id').val(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/admin/tree/tree-info/' + id,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(response) {
                        // console.log(response);
                        var html = '';
                        $.each(response.tree_name, (index, res) => {
                            if (res != null)
                                html += `<tr data-index="${index}">
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tree_name[]" value="${res}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" value="${response.quantity[index]}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="height[]" value="${response.height[index]}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="round[]" value="${response.round[index]}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly name="total[]" value="${response.total[index]}"></td>
                                    </tr>`;
                        });

                        $('#tree_info').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).on('blur', '#tree_info tr input', function(e) {
                // console.log($(this).closest('tr input'))
                $(this).closest('tr input').each(function() {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                })
            });
```

This code returns only one field that I selected but I need all inputs.

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, you're looking to sum up all the values in each individual column?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing...

```js
$(this).closest('tr input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

With...

```js
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

As mentioned in the comment below, the above does not answer your question directly. To sum up all values I would assume the below would work...

```js
$(document).on('blur', '#tree_info tr input', function(e) {
    let sumValue = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {
        sumValue += $(this).val();
    });
    console.log('The total sum value is', sumValue);
});
```

Comment: How does this 'sum all the values' as the OP requests?

Comment: Your question asks to 'sum the values', not just display them. If this answer solves your issue then your question is inaccurate and needs to be edited.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right, I didn't answer the question directly. I have updated my answer. Thanks!